# Mule won't allow POLL message processor to read file using file Inbound?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I have a small query, POLL message processor  not allowing to read Files from 'File Inbound' message processor?

I need to read the file for every 5 minutes (Schedule automatically) to proceed with further requirements. Is it possible using POLL?

How can be  file inbound  used in POLL. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: I recommend you perform this operation using the quartz connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you execute this operation using the quartz connector. Here's an example:

```
<flow name="repeatIntervalFileFlow" doc:name="repeatIntervalFileFlow">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" jobName="test" repeatInterval="300000">
        <quartz:event-generator-job/>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>               
    <flow-ref name="readFileFlow" doc:name="readFileFlow"/>        
</flow>

<flow name="readFileFlow" doc:name="readFileFlow">        
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="path" connector-ref="in" doc:name="File">
        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.txt" />
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="listo" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
   ...      
</flow>
```

I hope to help;

Comment: @ Julio: Thanks for your help. I will start implement it and let you know. Already we have Quartz why do Mule has introduced POLL. Do we have any specific reason???

Comment: Mule have Quartz in most of the versions, recently POLL has introduced. Do you have any idea what is the difference b/w Quartz and POLL. and why specifically POLL has introduced??  Quartz have a capability to do all the works which is  done by POLL. Then why POLL? I got confused..

Comment: with poll is not necessary use an inbound endpoint, just pooling and use the result as the source of the other flow. Pool has no support for cron expression, quartz yes; is usually used to poll outbound-endpoint.

Comment: Poll does now in fact support for Cron and Fixed frequency schedulers:http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Poll+Schedulers . Also one benefit of using poll is with an Mule EE cluster and the cluster can handle poll nomination and failover ootb(similar to to Quartz job stores).