# Difference between Mule ESB Poll and Quartz

Tags: mule, quartz

Can some help me to know the difference between mule Poll and Quartz component.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Abani, go through the Mulesoft documentation to understand these components and differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poll component is idle component best to use in cluster environment(Dont use Quartz) so it avoid invoking same jobs in all server. POll handle it by default.

**As per Docs:** -> Polling in a Cluster:
When running in a cluster, only the server identified as the primary node performs the polling. In case the primary node goes down, then another node in the cluster becomes the primary node and starts polling instead (failover).

**Quartz:**
Quartz can be placed anywhere in the flow.Its acts accordingly wherever you placed it.
For triggering files(Scenario as given in the below link) to any specific interval Quartz do well.Quartz have  Custom, event,schedule dispatch Job.

Need to use based on the requirement.

[Mule won't allow POLL message processor to read file using file Inbound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016029/mule-wont-allow-poll-message-processor-to-read-file-using-file-inbound).

If you are in cluster envt, recommend to use Poll.

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Both quartz, as well as poll scope, almost does the same thing. If you want to trigger the flow in regular intervals you can use the quartz.

But the advantage with the poll scope is you can set the polling frequency.and you can use the Cron job or expression to set the time.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct. Just to add that in non-clustered environment, you can still use Quartz cluster to achieve same functionality as Poll Scope.